Compact Hamiltonians in Quantum Mechanics
I recently learned about the spectral theorem for compact Hermitian operators (in an introductory functional analysis class):

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $T \in L(H)$ compact Hermitian. Then there exists an orthonormal basis $(e_n)$ of $H$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$. Moreover, the corresponding eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots \to 0$ (for $\dim H = \infty$).

I've been thinking about how to apply this to Quantum Mechanics (which I've never studied at a rigorous level). Say $H = L_2(\mathbb R)$ is our Hilbert space, and our Hamiltonian operator looks something like
$$
T = - \frac{\mathrm d^2}{\mathrm dx^2} + V(x).
$$
The first kink is that not everything in $L_2(\mathbb R)$ is twice-differentiable, but I think this has an easy fix. This post gives $e^{-x^2/2} H_n(x)$ as an orthogonal basis for $L_2(\mathbb R)$, so $T$ makes sense on the linear span of these (and is bounded... provided $V(x)$ is not too crazy?), which is dense in $H$, so extends to a unique bounded operator on $H$.
Is this correct? For which $V$ would $T$ actually be bounded?
For which $V$ would $T$ be compact, so that we may use the theorem above?
My intuition is that something like the harmonic oscillator would not have a compact Hamiltonian, since it has a sequence of distinct eigenvalues $\to \infty$, which contradicts the theorem, but something like the finite square well (or the Coulomb potential, in 3d) probably does.
Edit: I now know that such operators are almost never bounded, more or less because $\psi$ can be very small while oscillating very quickly so as to produce a large second derivative; sorry about my confusion. How, then, is the "Hermitian operators have a basis of eigenvectors" approach in QM made rigorous?

The coulomb potential also doesnt work at all, the hamiltonians spectrum contains $[0, \infty)$ in this case.

$T$ is not bounded even for $V=0$. Because that would imply that $d^2/dx^2$ can be extended continuously to all of $L^2$ which is wrong. There are also nice perturbation results that show that for almost all nice $V$ the Hamiltonian is unbounded.

@jd27 I see, thank you for your comment. Is there then some other theorem we could use to make the "Hermitian operators have orthonormal basis" approach in QM rigorous?
